# spark.read is not a member of package org.apache.spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, intellij-idea, jdbc

I'm trying to connect postgresql and spark on Intellij. However I'm getting `object read is not a member of package org.apache.spark` error even though I've included JDBC driver in my build.sbt.

I'm trying to follow this tutorial https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-jdbc.html and here is my scala code:

```scala
import org.apache.spark

object DBConn {

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    // Note: JDBC loading and saving can be achieved via either the load/save or jdbc methods
    // Loading data from a JDBC source
    val jdbcDF = spark.read
      .format("jdbc")
      .option("url", "jdbc:postgresql://host/db")
      .option("dbtable", "chroniker_log")
      .option("user", "username")
      .option("password", "password")
      .load()

    val connectionProperties = new Properties()
    connectionProperties.put("user", "username")
    connectionProperties.put("password", "password")
    val jdbcDF2 = spark.read
      .jdbc("jdbc:postgresql:dbserver", "schema.tablename", connectionProperties)
    // Specifying the custom data types of the read schema
    connectionProperties.put("customSchema", "id DECIMAL(38, 0), name STRING")
    val jdbcDF3 = spark.read
      .jdbc("jdbc:postgresql:dbserver", "schema.tablename", connectionProperties)
  }
}
```

build.sbt:

```
name := "DBConnect"

version := "0.1"

scalaVersion := "2.11.12"

val sparkVersion = "2.4.3"

resolvers ++= Seq(
  "apache-snapshots" at "http://repository.apache.org/snapshots/"
)

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % sparkVersion,
  "org.postgresql" % "postgresql" % "42.2.5"
)
```

I tried to simplify the problem by running spark-shell on the console. However, this following command also throws the same warning:

```
spark-shell --driver-class-path postgresql-42.2.5.jar --jars postgresql-42-2.5.jar -i src/main/scala/DBC
onn.scala
```

interestingly once I'm in spark-shell after the above code fail, it starts recognizing `spark.read` and successfully connects to the database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need an instance of `SparkSession` that is often called `spark` (including spark-shell). See [this tutorial](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-getting-started.html):

```
val spark = SparkSession
  .builder()
  .appName("Spark SQL basic example")
  .config("spark.some.config.option", "some-value")
  .getOrCreate()
```

So `read` is not a method in a package object but a method in class `SparkSession`